# Regex works but not with egrep in bash on Windows

Tags: regex, windows, bash, grep

I have a text file `test.txt` with the following content:

```
20001
200134
20103040
203004038002
```

I want to use the following egrep command to show the matches:

```
egrep '^(?!(?:.*?0){6,})(?=(?:.*?0){3,})[0-9]+$' test.txt
```

However for some reason egrep doesn't output anything. But I can see that my regex does work on regex101 link:
https://regex101.com/r/XZDonL/1

Am I using egrep wrong? Because I don't know what I'm doing wrong. By the way I'm using bash on Windows.

Comment: try `grep -P`, lookarounds are not supported in EREs

Comment: `my regex does work on regex101` means exactly that, that your regexp works on the web site regex101, no more and no less. It specifically does NOT mean that it'll work in any given command line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookaround notation `(?!` is not supported in `egrep` but you might try `grep -P` if supported to make it perl compatible.

It is seems you want to match numbers which contain 3 - 5 times a zero.

Another option to match this is to match 0+ times a digit `[1-9]` with 3 times a zero and 2 times an optional zero.

You might use this pattern with egrep:

```
^[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*0?[1-9]*0?[1-9]*$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqbDw7/1)

For example:

```
egrep '^[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*0[1-9]*0?[1-9]*0?[1-9]*$' test.txt
```

Comment: An ERE to match numbers containing 3-5 0s is just `^([1-9]*0){3,5}[1-9]*$`

Comment: You are right, it is shorter and cleaner.